# Extending IdentityUser in Asp.Net Core Identity 2.0 when it's a NuGet package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

In this blog [ASP.NET Core 2.1.0-preview1: Introducing Identity UI as a library](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/) I found that the concept of identity in ASP.Net Core 2.0 is being shipped as a NuGet package.

I'm working on a project where I need to extend the included IdentityUser to be in multiple one to many relationships.

I would like to add properties onto my user class like List and List.

With IdentityUser in a NuGet package how do people customize it? Does everyone opt out of the NuGet package if they want to customize it?

Comment: don't see how you can opt out of NuGets when you want to customize it. I sense you are mistaking some concepts here. Did you run into any difficulties while doing this customization with NuGets?

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for, but classes such as `IdentityUser` can be found in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores` NuGet package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that blog is specifically talking about UI elements, whereas you seem to be asking about back-end code...

If you just want to add some custom stuff to the User model, this is already supported:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Basically you can create a custom class which derives (inherits from) `IdentityUser`, add custom properties to this, then when setting up Identity you can use this rather than the stock `IdentityUser`.